# Why didn't Ruby timeout raise an error?

Tags: ruby, timeout

Why didn't this code raise an error?

```
require 'net/ping'
host = Net::Ping::External.new('1.1.1.1')

Timeout.timeout(3) do
  until host.ping?
    sleep(1)
    host = Net::Ping::External.new('1.1.1.1')
  end
end
```

This example raised an error:

```
require 'net/ping'

Timeout.timeout(3) do
  until false
    sleep(4)
  end
end
```

ruby-2.0.0-p594 [ x86_64 ]. Perhaps it's problem with ruby version? Because with ruby-2.1.3 [ x86_64 ] all is ok.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't put essential information in comments. Instead, edit your question and add that in as if you'd entered it in originally.

Comment: I suspect the problem is related to the IP timeout. It's blocking the code trying to ping a non-reachable address. Trying using `ping 1.1.1.1` or `traceroute 1.1.1.1` and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you as I understand IP has own timeout.

Comment: Yep, and that bites people all the time.